# How do I recreate this sound (in Ableton)?

Tags: sound-effects, synthesizer, home-studio

I've been trying to recreate [this sound](https://youtube.com/shorts/qOmlocP-3s8?feature=share) from a song I made when I was quite young. I used GarageBand for this, not Ableton, but due to the advanced level of Ableton I thought I'd still be able to recreate it. From what I remember, I took some sort of string/bell-type synth and played around with all the settings till I came to this.

I will say, however, despite my initial suspicion of a (pluck) string or bell base sound, I haven't made any success with either. The farthest I've gotten was with the muffle, but clearly there's more to this sound than a muffle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both sound like a sine wave with different ADSR processing:

- A: attack
- D: delay (sometimes not provided)
- S: sustain
- R: release

Think of [ADSR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Envelope_(music)) as someone turning up the volume of this instrument quickly at the beginning (A), lowering it a bit (D), keeping it for a while (S) and finally lowering it again (R) . Depending on their values you'll get e.g. the soft bell-like sound in the beginning, or the one with the longer sustain.

On a synthesizer plug-in this may be an option you can use. See, if GB provides a synthesizer as an instrument. If yes, use two and adjust their ADSR individually. If not: ... well ...

Note, that the synthesizer instrument will generate a long lasting tone for a given note, where its volume (envelope) is modulated as I described.

Comment: _Decay_, not Delay. Also, Release is the drop-off of after you release the note :)

Comment: Right :) Blame it half to autocorrection ;)